# How do you make a stepper motor move at decimal (such as 0.5) steps?

Tags: stepper

if I were to use a code with the following format,

```
//some loop
digitalWrite(STEP_PIN,HIGH);
digitalWrite(STEP_PIN,LOW);
//
```

each loop would make the motor move at one step. With this loop I can also make the motor move at 200 or other integer steps. However, is it possible to make the motor move at decimal steps such as 0.4?

Comment: It is called microstepping. There are modules with current control that can do microstepping. The easiest solution for you can be a geared stepper motor.

Comment: Depends on you stepper driver. It needs to support microsteps. Which driver do you use?